# i want activity indicator on collectionview cell until image loads from webserver

Tags: ios, iphone

How would I know when i have got the data and now when i need to hide `activity indicator` and show image .. i want `activity indicato`r on `collectionview` cell until image loads from webserver. I did all but to no avail . Please provide guidance. I m using `gif` image to load `activity indiactor`

```
 NSURL *urlSTR=nil;
    urlSTR = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"list_loader_Anim@2x" withExtension:@"gif"];

    UIImageView* dataimage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 31, 31)];
    dataimage.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 31, 31);

    dataimage.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlSTR]];

    dataimage.center = CGPointMake(cell.frame.size.width/2, cell.frame.size.height/2-70);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at SDWebImage:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

It gives you great way to download image asynchronously.